# Wishes, words, and gifts *for* the birth?

Tags: prepositions

> We would like to thank everyone for their heart felt wishes, kind words and wonderful gifts **for** the birth of our son.

Does this sound correct?  We aren't sure about using "for" in this situation.

Comment: It sounds good, but you need "heart-felt wishes".

Comment: @Mick Shouldn't it be "heartfelt"?

Comment: @SovereignSun Blame my inordinate affection for the humble hyphen. It seems that everyone is trying to get rid of it. I'm a sentimentalist at heart.

Comment: @Mick I see. so both are equally right?

Comment: @SovereignSun Do you mean "Am I wrong?" Let's just say that my Oxford Concise Dictionary only lists *heartfelt*. :$

Answer (score 1):

Good one.

I would say

... **on** the birth of our son.

OR

... **on the occasion of** the birth of our son. [credit to John]

on and for are often misused in wishes.

Right : Congratulations **on** the new addition to your family.

Wrong : Congratulations **for** the arrival of your baby boy.

Comment: Well, I'm not so sure about the *on* the birth.

Anyone to clarify the doubts?

Comment: Google ngram isn't any help in distinguishing between on, for, and at...

Comment: I'm sticking to *on* then.

Comment: I mentally change "on" to "on the occasion of", and it works well that way.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It sounds good too.